# Egg Dropping Puzzle - Suggestion needed

Tags: algorithm

**Problem Statement**

Egg dropping refers to a class of problems in which it is important to find the correct response without exceeding a (low) number of certain failure states. In a toy example, there is a tower of  floors, and an egg dropper with  ideal eggs. The physical properties of the ideal egg is such that it will shatter if it is dropped from floor  or above, and will have no damage whatsoever if it is dropped from floor  or below. The problem is to find a strategy such that the egg dropper can determine the floor  in as few egg drops as possible. This problem has many applications in the real world such as avoiding a call out to the slow HDD, or attempting to minimize cache misses, or running a large number of expensive queries on a database.

[Problem Statement and Solution Analysis](https://brilliant.org/wiki/egg-dropping/)

When we have N number of eggs and K number of floors the following code finds the minimum number of drops using quadratic equation with time complexity of **O(N)**.

```
(function() {
  var eggs = 3, floors = 2;

  function findFloor(eggs, floors) {
    if (eggs === 1 || floors === 0 || floors === 1) {
      return floors;
    }

    var minDrops = Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + (8 * floors))) / 2);
    return Math.min(minDrops, findFloor(eggs - 1, minDrops));
  }

  console.log(findFloor(eggs, floors));
})();
```

I have tested with some test cases but can anyone suggest, will this work for all the scenarios?

Comment: The quadratic equation that you are using only works in case of 2 eggs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not always produce the correct results. You have used this formula:

[image]

But that formula only provides a meaningful result in case the number of eggs is two. Note how the number of eggs is not appearing in it, only the number of floors ( ***k*** ).

#### Counter example

Take for instance the case with 4 floors and 3 eggs. Your function returns 2, but if that were the correct answer, then which floors would you pick in those two attempts?

Let's drop from floor 3: egg breaks. Then throw from floor 1: egg does not break. Now we don't know whether the answer is floor 1 or 2. We would need to drop one more egg to be sure.

Maybe start at floor 2?: egg is OK. Then throw from floor 4: egg breaks. Now we don't know whether the answer is floor 2 or 3. We would need to drop one more egg to be sure.

So, in the worst case we need to drop at least 3 eggs.

#### Conclusion

Your algorithm is not correct. The article you refer two has correct implementations (although there are some typos with variable names). Here they are in JavaScript:

```
function getNumDropsRecursive(eggs, floors) {
    if (eggs == 1 || floors == 0 || floors == 1) {
        return floors
    }

    let minimum = Infinity;
    for (let floor = 1; floor <= floors; floor++) {
        minimum = Math.min(
            minimum, 
            1 + Math.max(getNumDropsRecursive(eggs - 1, floor - 1), 
                         getNumDropsRecursive(eggs, floors - floor))
        )
    }

    return minimum;
}

function getNumDropsDP(eggs, floors) {
    const numdrops = [
        null, 
        [...Array(floors+1).keys()], 
        ...Array.from(Array(eggs-1), _ => [0, 1])
    ];
    for (let remainingEggs = 2; remainingEggs <= eggs; remainingEggs++) {
        for (let choices = 2; choices <= floors; choices++) {
            let minimum = Infinity;
            for (let dropAt = 1; dropAt <= choices; dropAt++) {
                minimum = Math.min(minimum, 
                    1 + Math.max(numdrops[remainingEggs-1][dropAt-1],
                                 numdrops[remainingEggs][choices-dropAt])
                );
            }
            numdrops[remainingEggs][choices] = minimum;
        }
    }
    return numdrops[eggs][floors];
}
```

Using the first one is not advised as it starts to get really slow with arguments above 20.

I would also name your function differently. The function does not find a floor, but the *number of drops* you need in the worst case to find the floor. So a name like `getNumDrops` would be more telling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the known [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Egg_dropping_puzzle) is `O(n log k)`. Here are some mismatches:

```js
/*
W(n,k) = 1 + min{max(W(n − 1, x − 1), W(n,k − x)): x = 1, 2, ..., k }

with W(n,0) = 0 for all n > 0 and W(1,k) = k for all k.
*/

function f(n,k){
  if (k == 0 && n > 0)
    return 0;
    
  if (n == 1)
    return k;
    
  let best = Infinity;
  
  for (let x=1; x<=k; x++)
    best = Math.min(best, Math.max(f(n-1, x-1), f(n, k-x)));
  
  return 1 + best;
}

function findFloor(eggs, floors) {
    if (eggs === 1 || floors === 0 || floors === 1) {
      return floors;
    }

    var minDrops = Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + (8 * floors))) / 2);
    return Math.min(minDrops, findFloor(eggs - 1, minDrops));
}
  
for (let i=1; i<10; i++){
  for (let j=1; j<10; j++){
    let a = f(i,j);
    let b = findFloor(i,j);
    
    if (a != b){
      console.log(`n,k: ${i},${j}; f: ${a}; findFloors: ${b}`);
    }
  }
}
```